Posterior probability of cointegration rank
I've been trying to learn Bayesian estimation of VECM. Right now I have troubles figuring how to estimate posterior probabilities of cointegration rank values.
I looked into the bvartools library in R for ready implementations (because they also typically include references in documentation).
The documentation entries draw_posterior.bvecmodel and post_coint_kls both reference a paper by Koop et al. In it the authors detail prior elicitation and inference for the model
$$\Delta y_t=\alpha\beta^Tx_t+\varepsilon_t$$
and claim that it is somehow possible to calculate posterior probabilities of cointegrating ranks. However, there is no algorithm in the article and apparently no implementation in bvartools.
Is there any other literature on the subject, preferably with details on inference of cointegrating ranks probabilities? Perhaps, there is a straightforward way to calculate the probabilities?
